# How do I save a Google now suggestion so I can read it later?

Tags: google-now

Google now has started giving me suggestions to interesting articles, but I only seem to see them during the day when I'm working and don't have time to read them.

How do I save them for reading later, without going to the article and emailing it to myself?

Comment: Make bookmark of it in browser.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately the result is still the same in that I have to visit the page or risk the card vanishing before I get to see it. Not great when I'm in meetings!

Comment: Or you can take screenshot of the card and later search for that article

Comment: There isn't official functionality for this. You're best off using something like Pocket/Instapaper or taking a screenshot like Ash-Ishh says. Anyway, the cards should stick around for some time.

Comment: you could raise a feature request for this

Comment: I don't think google has thought about this feature, this is the most needed feature. I have posted this in Google forums, please upvote the options request, so that Google finds it as more needed feature. Link here https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/37113615?hl=en&dark=1